# Animation between drawImage and canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas that draws the letter 'a' with a box:

```
 var cxt = document.getElementById('someCanvas').getContext('2d');
 cxt.strokeRect(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight);
 cxt.fillText('a', someX, someY);
```

if I want to animate this to move and not leave the previous drawn canvas behind, I will need **clearRect** and re-draw it again:

```
 cxt.clearRect(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight);
 //cxt.strokeRect..
 //cxt.fillText..
```

However, with drawImage, I can just increment its x/y without needing to clear/re-draw it again:

```
 cxt.drawImage(src, someX, someY);
```

I was wondering, would there be any performance difference of these two methods if I wanted more letters/others? Does **drawImage** clear itself the same way as **clearRect**?